# Fetching users with delta and memberOf filter from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to filter users based on MemberOf when doing a delta query?

I've tried the following (and a numerous variations on OData syntax) but with no success.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$filter=MemberOf eq '1f3f7dec-679c-4e3a-bc0b-aa43000c5a31'

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$filter=MemberOf/any(g:g, Id eq '1f3f7dec-679c-4e3a-bc0b-aa43000c5a31')
```

Error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "906cdcb0-cf3d-4eda-8c0b-2cdd9002cc4f",
            "date": "2017-12-07T10:45:41"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately memberOf is not a supported filter. The Microsoft Graph delta API only supports filtering based on immutable properties.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is this something that is planned? Makes more sense to monitor changes for a subset of users than all accounts, especially on a big AD. It will generate quite a lot extra traffic to Graph API since we need to fetch everything and throw away on client side then.

Comment: This is something that we definitely want to support as it is a logical extension to the existing functionality. However, we don't know when it will happen.

Comment: You also do not seem to support any filters on /memberOf...really annoying as its a prime use case (get all user groups that startwith a suffix)

Comment: @Trey, any update on this functionality as it still direly needed in order to drill down on more granular delta changes on users (i.e. their memberships).  This should help cut down on the number of API requests when needing to track this attribute.